A movie about a woman told by a fortune teller that her husband will die
Okay so a few years ago I watched this movie that was some sort of a romantic drama. 
So what I can remember is: There's an elderly couple who lost their son in high school because he overdosed. 
There’s a young woman who goes to this fortune teller (also a woman, I think she was chubby and had black hair) and the fortune teller tells her that her future is awful and that her husband will die.
Now the most important part of the movie that I can remember is: The woman is with her friends on a field and her husband is playing with his guy friends, they are playing football, so someone throws the ball at him and it hits him in the heart and he has a heart attack and dies. 
I can't remember any of the actors. But I know that the movie was somewhere between 2003-2016. It was American. That’s pretty much all that I can remember

Indeed, I might know this but the country\language and the approximate year\decade of release will help tremendously. Do you happen to know them? And did you recognize any of the actors?

That’s the biggest problem, I cannot remember any of the actors. I know that it was somewhere between 2003-20016 but that doesn’t help much either....

OK. Was it American\in English?

Yes, it was american.

This is the romantic drama film Feast of Love from 2007 with Morgan Freeman, Greg Kinnear, Radha Mitchell and Selma Blair.

The movie deals with love and its various incarnations, set within a community of friends in Portland, Oregon. Harry Stevenson provides narration about how love can affect one's life.

One of the stories there is about a woman told by a fortune teller that her husband is going to die; he later dies of a heart attack after playing football. And another story is about an older couple whose only son died of an overdose (the husband is the narrator). Here's the trailer:



